# Making a login forum in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, passwords

```
Checker = 'Incorrect'
name = input('Please Enter Your Name: ')

password = input('Please Enter Your Password: ')
if password == 'badger123':
    print('Checking Password...')
else:
    print(Checker)
if Checker == 'Incorrect':
    exit()


import time
time.sleep(5)
print('Password is Correct')
time.sleep(3)
input('Press Enter to Continue...')



print ('Hello' , name)



import time

time.sleep(1)

print ("Closing Python...")

import time

time.sleep(5)

input('Press Enter to continue...')

exit()
```

I need help , the correct password is badger123 but even if I enter the correct password it will print 'password is correct' and then exit but I want it to ignore exit and continue. When the wrong password is entered then the program will print incorrect and will exit. The programs reacts correctly when the incorrect password is entered but not when the correct password is entered. I NEED HELP!

Comment: You only need to import module once. Also by convention your variable names should be lowercase or camel case. Also before writing please at least read something like Python the Hard Way or Dive into Python. It will save you and us a lot of time.

Comment: Basically, what I want to happen is when I enter the wrong password it should then print checking password... When I enter the correct password is entered it should say checking password and then say password is correct and then is should say press enter to continue and basically you get the idea.

Comment: Many things can be improved. Such as merging the second `if` statement on line 9 with the `else` statement. Or doing away with both of them and replacing with `if not`

Answer (score 2):

The value of Checker never actually changes, so

```
if Checker == 'Incorrect':
    exit()
```

always evaluates to `True`, which means `exit()` is always called.

One solution is to do the checking in the if statement

```
import time

password = input('Please Enter Your Password: ')
if password == 'badger123':
    print('Password is Correct...')
else:
    print('Password Incorrect')
    exit()

time.sleep(3)
input('Press Enter to Continue...')

print ('Hello' , name)

time.sleep(1)

print ("Closing Python...")
input('Press Enter to continue...')
```

Answer (score 0):

First you only need to import a module once (by convention at the top of your file), and not each time you want to use a function.

The problem you describe is impossible with the code you show

```
Checker = 'Incorrect'
if Checker == 'Incorrect':
    exit()
```

Since you assign `'Incorrect'` to Checker and never changes it after that, the rest of your code is not executed, and your program will never print `'password is correct'`, it will however print `'Checking Password...'` when the correct password is entered and then exit because Checker is always the same, it's like doing `if 1 == 1:exit()`

Comment: I understand , If I change the value of checker to exit it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Why it isn't working

You set value checker to "incorrect"

When the password is found to be correct, nothing is done about it. Nothing notifies the program in any way that the correct password has been entered. You can see in program that all the program does to acknowledge that the password is correct is simply say that it is "checking" and nothing else. 3 lines later the program will find that checker is still "incorrect" because the program, seeing that the password is correct does nothing to change checker so line 9 is inevitably going to happen.

Fix:

Put line 10 with the `else` statement and remove line 9. So your code will look something like.

```
password = input('Please enter your password: ')
if password == 'badger123':
    print('Checking Password...')
else:
    print(Checker)
    exit()
```

I can suggest an improvement.

```
password = input('Please enter your password: ')
if not password == 'badger123':
    print(Checker)
    exit()
print('Checking Password...')
```

Comment: Try the code yourself. I tried the fix but it did not work.

Comment: Did you cut line 10? Not copy, cut.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be the ANSWER to my question! , All I did is I changed the value of Checker. But now when the person gets the password wrong I want the program to automatically Restart . How do I do that?

```
Checker = 'Incorrect'
name = input('Please Enter Your Name: ')

password = input('Please Enter Your Password: ')
if password == 'badger123':
    print('Checking Password...')
else:
    print(Checker)
    Checker = exit()
if Checker == 'Incorrect':
    input(Checker)




import time
time.sleep(5)
print('Password is Correct')
time.sleep(3)
input('Press Enter to Continue...')



print ('Hello' , name)



import time

time.sleep(1)

print ("Closing Python...")

import time

time.sleep(5)

input('Press Enter to continue...')

exit()
```